# The PanGestureHandler translationY resets to 0 once the gesture begins even though I am adding an offset value to it. How is that possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I have created a simple PanGestureHandler and want it to start from previous position when the gesture begins. I am setting the translationY value to the offsetY value when the gesture ends, which works perfectly and when the gesture begins I'm setting the sum of offsetY(which is the previous translationY) and the translationY to translationY, which on debugging shows the correct translation value. But that doesn't reflect on the View. Since I'm new to reanimated I don't know why that happens. I also couldn't find much resources on the implementation of gesture handlers using functional components.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

My Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dimensions, Text } from 'react-native'
import { PanGestureHandler, State } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

import Animated, { add, block, cond, debug, eq, event, Extrapolate, interpolate, set, useCode, useValue } from 'react-native-reanimated';

const {height,width}=Dimensions.get("window")

export default function Pan() {
    const translationY = useValue(0)
    const offsetY = useValue(0)
    const gestureState = useValue(State.UNDETERMINED)

    const onGestureEvent = event([{
        nativeEvent: {
        translationY,
        state: gestureState
        },
    }], { useNativeDriver: true });

    useCode(() => block([
        cond(eq(gestureState, State.BEGAN), [set(translationY, add(translationY, offsetY)),debug('offsetY', translationY)]),
        cond(eq(gestureState, State.END), [set(offsetY, translationY), debug('translateY', offsetY)])
    ]), [])

    const translateY = translationY

    return (
        <PanGestureHandler {...{onGestureEvent}} onHandlerStateChange={onGestureEvent}>
            <Animated.View style={{ height: height * 45 / 100, backgroundColor:'red', width: width, transform: [{ translateY }] }}>
                <Text>PanGesture</Text>
            </Animated.View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";
import {Dimensions, Text, View} from "react-native";
import {PanGestureHandler} from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import Animated, {
Extrapolate,
useSharedValue,
useAnimatedGestureHandler,
interpolate,
useAnimatedStyle,
} from "react-native-reanimated";

const {height, width} = Dimensions.get("window");

const Test: React.FC = () => {
const translationY = useSharedValue(0);

const onGestureEvent = useAnimatedGestureHandler(
    {
        onStart: (_, ctx) => {
            ctx.y = translationY.value;
        },
        onActive: (event, ctx) => {
            translationY.value = event.translationY + ctx.y;
        },
    },
    [translationY.value],
);

const animatedStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const translateY = interpolate(
        translationY.value,
        [0, height - (height * 45) / 100],
        [0, height - (height * 45) / 100],
        Extrapolate.CLAMP,
    );
    return {
        height: (height * 45) / 100,
        backgroundColor: "red",
        width,
        transform: [{translateY}],
    };
}, [translationY.value]);

return (
    <View style={{height, width, backgroundColor: "yellow"}}>
        <PanGestureHandler {...{onGestureEvent}}>
            <Animated.View style={animatedStyles}>
                <Text>PanGesture</Text>
            </Animated.View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
    </View>
);
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: Tried this. But it still resets to 0 on touch

Comment: I Checked this and it worked. Here Check it out on https://snack.expo.io/@alirezahadjar/quiet-kiwi

Comment: Tried running it on snack. It doesn't work for android and ios. Only works on web

Comment: this works perfectly right, and it is so much simpler. but for this, you need to upgrade your reanimated version to the latest one. for installation follow the docs: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation

Comment: this code does work. but unfortunately I'm using reanimated 1